# Can't get an image (image view) under a transparent statusbar

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I'm trying to get an image under the status bar in Android Studio. So far I've managed to get the status bar fully transparent, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually draw images under it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private int newPosition = 0;
    private int currentPosition = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new InfoFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_info:
                            selectedFragment = new InfoFragment();
                            newPosition = 1;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_event:
                            selectedFragment = new EventsFragment();
                            newPosition = 2;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_shop:
                            selectedFragment = new ShopFragment();
                            newPosition = 3;
                            break;
                    }

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                    if (currentPosition < newPosition) {
                        //transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
                    } else if (currentPosition > newPosition) {
                        //transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                    }

                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment, "FRAGMENT").commit();
                    currentPosition = newPosition;
                    return true;
                }
            };
}
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The minSdkVersion is `22` and the targetSdkVersion is `28`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `android:fitSystemWindows` and/or the [WindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets) API's.

`fitSystemWindows` basically tells the system that you want your views to fit into the whole screen. Opposed to the default, where your view only renders fits from below the statusbar to just above the navigationbar.

`WindowInsets` can be used to further fine-tune where system UI will or will not be drawn.

For your usecase, `android:fitSystemWindows` should suffice

Comment: I've found that already and tried using it but nothing actually changes

Comment: In that case, perhaps show the code you tried, that makes it easier to see what is going on. What also matters are your minSdk and targetSdk version, and the libraries you use. E.g. support design, appcompat or related libraries

Comment: I've edited my post with what seems to me the important code